# Type script- React native : How to modify json response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, react-hooks

What is the correct way to modify json response ,
My goal is to display all the `MaintroomName` belonging to the same `Plsectn`

**This is the function that needs to modify to get the same structure
which I mentioned below that I am interested in reaching.**

```
useEffect(() => {
    BtpBridgeModule.loadDataFromSdk(
      'GushSet',
      [],
      { PlantID: userData.plant, LocationID: userData.LocationID },
      undefined,
      0,
    ).then(function (dataResolved) {
      let aResults = JSON.parse(dataResolved).value;
    });
  }, [userData.LocationID, userData.plant]);
```

The json look like this :

```
[
   {
      "Maintroom":"221",
      "MaintroomName":"gogi",
      "Plsectn":"22",
      "PlsectnName":"pardehan"
   },
   {
      "Maintroom":"222",
      "MaintroomName":"nahaleymenash",
      "Plsectn":"22",
      "PlsectnName":"pardehan"
   },
{
     
      "Maintroom":"231",
      "MaintroomName":"gvul",
      "Plsectn":"23",
      "PlsectnName":"meshulash"
   },
   {
     
      "Maintroom":"232",
      "MaintroomName":"daro",
      "Plsectn":"23",
      "PlsectnName":"meshulash"
   },
]
```

**I wanna change it to this structure :**

```
[
    {
      title: PlsectnName,
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: PlsectnName,
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
        { key: MaintroomName, value: false, checked: false },
      ],
    },
]
```

**Note - each `Plsectn` can have a dynamic number of `MaintroomName`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Algorithm to sort your data

```js
// Your response data
const data = [
   {
      "Maintroom":"221",
      "MaintroomName":"gogi",
      "Plsectn":"22",
      "PlsectnName":"pardehan"
   },
   {
      "Maintroom":"222",
      "MaintroomName":"nahaleymenash",
      "Plsectn":"22",
      "PlsectnName":"pardehan"
   },
   {
     
      "Maintroom":"231",
      "MaintroomName":"gvul",
      "Plsectn":"23",
      "PlsectnName":"meshulash"
   },
   {
     
      "Maintroom":"232",
      "MaintroomName":"daro",
      "Plsectn":"23",
      "PlsectnName":"meshulash"
   },
];

// Variable to track duplicate keys (PlsectnName)
let keys = [];

// Result after sorting the data
let result = [];

// Algorithm to sort the data
data.forEach((obj) => {
  if(!keys.includes(obj.PlsectnName)){
    result.push({
      title: obj.PlsectnName,
      checked: false,
      data: [
        { key: obj.MaintroomName, value: obj.Maintroom, checked: false }
      ]
    });
    keys.push(obj.PlsectnName);
  }
  
  else {
    result.forEach((subObj,index) => {
      if(subObj.title == obj.PlsectnName){
        subObj.data = [...subObj.data, { key: obj.MaintroomName, value: obj.Maintroom, checked: false }]
        result[index] = subObj;
      }
    });
  }
})

// Log the result
console.log(result)
```

(Note: If you want to set the ***`value`*** as ***`false`*** then change ***`value: obj.Maintroom`*** to ***`value: false`***)

#### Implementing the Algorithm in your ***`useEffect`*** function.

```js
// Algorithm as function to sort your data
const sortData = (data) => {
    // Variable to track duplicate keys (PlsectnName)
    let keys = [];

    // Result after sorting the data
    let result = [];

    // Algorithm to sort the data
    data.forEach((obj) => {
        if(!keys.includes(obj.PlsectnName)){
            result.push({
                title: obj.PlsectnName,
                checked: false,
                data: [
                    { key: obj.MaintroomName, value: obj.Maintroom, checked: false }
                ]
            });
            keys.push(obj.PlsectnName);
        }
  
        else {
            result.forEach((subObj,index) => {
                if(subObj.title == obj.PlsectnName){
                    subObj.data = [...subObj.data, { key: obj.MaintroomName, value: obj.Maintroom, checked: false }]
                    result[index] = subObj;
                }
            });
        }
    })

    // return the result
    return result;
}

// Your function
useEffect(() => {
    BtpBridgeModule.loadDataFromSdk(
        'GushSet',
        [],
        { PlantID: userData.plant, LocationID: userData.LocationID },
        undefined,
        0,
    ).then(function (dataResolved) {
        let aResults = JSON.parse(dataResolved).value;
        // Added code
        let sortedResult = sortData(aResults)
        // Here sortedResult is your final data
    });
}, [userData.LocationID, userData.plant]);
```

Comment: Can you show me your example with my function?
Show me how you integrate it into my function?

Comment: @emma I've updated my code. Check the last code block. And if it helps you then make sure to upvote and mark the answer as the solution. So, others can be also benefited from this answer. Thank you :)

Comment: How to get the objects as they are now and also the next object  ?

Comment: ***`aResults`*** have the old value and ***`sortedResult`*** have the new value. If you need old value you have to use ***`aResults`***.

Comment: I want the sortedResult but also add to it the only the next value.